# android first tab intent oncreate always called regardless we set tab2 as default tab

Tags: android, tabwidget

Following is the example of tabs with intent data.

While debugging i found that always when first tab we add in tab host in our case following tab

```
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
                    .setIndicator("list")
                    .setContent(new Intent(this, List1.class)));
```

oncreate method of "List1" intent get called regardless it is our current tab or not even if if i define tab2 as a current tab how to fix this ?

```
public class Tabs3 extends TabActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1")
                .setIndicator("list")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, List1.class)));

        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2")
                .setIndicator("photo list")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, List8.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));

        // This tab sets the intent flag so that it is recreated each time
        // the tab is clicked.
        tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3")
                .setIndicator("destroy")
                .setContent(new Intent(this, Controls2.class)
                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP)));
    }
}
```

Comment: So, you want to add all the tabs, but have something other than the first tab be selected on default, and you don't want the List1 Activity to be created until you click on the tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> setDefaultTab(1);

seems not to be working in TabActivity when separate Activities are used as Tab Content.

Use following instead of this method,

> **tabHost.setCurrentTab(1);**

This will set "photo list" (i.e second tab) as the selected or default tab...

Comment: I have the same issue, and no this doesn't work. It does set the selected tab, but the onCreate of the first tab gets called no matter what.

Comment: same error here, the current tab works but the first tab oncreate is still also called.

Answer (score 0):

I have found this same behavior as well, and I do not have a specific fix.  But I do know of a work-around.

Instead of attaching Activities to each tab, attach a View to each tab. You can then handle the data passing very easily as each view will be in the same Activity. This also eliminates the need to pass information using Intents. Furthermore, you can create (or inflate) your Views as you need them and with more control.

Good luck,
-scott